# Tweak not working

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm trying hook IOKit framework (ios 10) to change my serial number
Build successful but when i test on my device result still my real serial number 
Anybody known why?
Here is my source code

```
#import <substrate.h>


typedef mach_port_t io_object_t;
typedef io_object_t io_registry_entry_t;
typedef UInt32 IOOptionBits;

extern "C" CFTypeRef IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(io_registry_entry_t entry, CFStringRef key, CFAllocatorRef allocator, IOOptionBits options);



static CFTypeRef (*orig_registryEntry)(io_registry_entry_t entry,  CFStringRef key, CFAllocatorRef allocator, IOOptionBits options);

CFTypeRef replaced_registryEntry(io_registry_entry_t entry,  CFStringRef key, CFAllocatorRef allocator, IOOptionBits options) {
    CFTypeRef retval = NULL;

    if(key == CFSTR("IOPlatformSerialNumber")){
        retval = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const unsigned char *)"F17JBBBBAAAA", 12);
    }
    else
        retval = orig_registryEntry(entry, key, allocator, options);

    return retval;
}


%ctor
{
    MSHookFunction((void *)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty, (void *)replaced_registryEntry, (void **)&orig_registryEntry);
    %init();
}
```

Comment: You want to change it system wide or in a specific process?

Comment: in system wide :D

Comment: Then you have to load your tweak into every process. On iOS that kind of information is usually requested using `MGGetAnswer` function from `libMobileGestalt.dylib`. Inside it calls the same `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty` to get the information.

Comment: i known mggetanswer but i dont want to use it

Comment: What I mean by that is there is no central place where this data is obtained. No central daemon that everyone connects to through XPC, for example, in order to access this information which would be much easier to hook. Everyone reads it directly from IOKit. This means that you can't easily hook it system wide. You would have to load your tweak into every iOS process that reads this data.